# Is there ANY way to convert System.Type to a user-defined class?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

So I'm trying to set up a self-updating help command for my Discord bot, that's all you need to know there.
To data specifically from my commands, they all derive from my baseclass ModuleArchetype, and I'm using Reflection to get a list of all the command data to use in this self-updating list.

The magic goal here is to access the data in each of these lovely constructors I have in each command module.

```
static Banana()
{
    Alias = "banana";
    Summary = "bananas are cool";
}
```

I've successfully been able to check whether or not a Type inherits ModuleArchetype.

```
List<ModuleArchetype> Output = new List<ModuleArchetype>; //Modules to return
var TypeList = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();

foreach(Type t in TypeList)
{
    if(t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ModuleArchetype)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.Name); //to verify the check is working
        Output.Add(); //the issue
    }
}
```

But...

```
Output.Add(t); //Obviously doesn't work
Output.Add((ModuleArchetype)t); //Nope, doesn't work
Output.Add(t as ModuleArchetype); //Nope
```

How do I get this type into a form that the list will play nice with?

Comment: `t` is a `Type`, how does that have anything to do with an _instance_ of your `ModuleArchetype` class?  Honestly this really seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Why do you feel that you need Reflection for this?  What does the static `Banana` have to do with the rest of your question?

Comment: `List<ModuleArchetype>` should really be `List<Type>`

Comment: Or you need to create an instance of each type and cast it. But either way, you need to make a clearer distinction between a type and an instance of the type.

Comment: Polymorphism/Interface is your friend.

Comment: You are looking for Activator.CreateInstance.

Comment: That really depends on how you plan to use `Output`.

Comment: Do all `ModuleArchetype` classes have the same static properties (e.g. `Alias` and `Description`)? Or are they unique per class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This...

```
List<ModuleArchetype>
```

...is a list that can contain ***instances of*** classes inherit from ModuleArchetype. It is not a list of types or a list of classes themselves.

I'm guessing that list will be utterly useless to you, since you appear to be interested in the static members, and static members are not contained in instances.

If you need a list of types that correspond to classes that inherit from ModuleArchetype, you need

```
List<Type>
```

Once you have stored all the types in the list, you can access their static members via Reflection, like this:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    var properties = item.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
}
```

If you want to get the Alias property of Banana, you'd end up using:

```
var aliasProperty = list.Where( t => t.Name == "Banana" )
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Single( p => p.Name == "Alias" );
var currentValue = aliasProperty.Invoke(null) as string;
Console.WriteLine(currentValue); //Should be "banana"
```

Of course, if you know you want the Alias property of Banana, it is wayyyy easier to type

```
var currentValue = Banana.Alias;
```

It is not possible to create a list where retrieving an item will give you access to static members, as the type information in the list isn't adequate for the compiler to have any idea what the unique properties or methods are for each different element.

Comment: What are you using to make `Invoke()` available? It's not showing up in Intellisense, and the compiler is complaining about it.

Comment: Sorry, should be GetValue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a type to a list, since it is a type. You have to define an object to add it to the list.

If you are creating a plugin system or something like that. It is recommended you create a interface. This will have the ability to easily create the list of the objects, and to get data from the objects.

I've done this with a open-source TCP server where a client can send a command to the server. And the server will use the list of plugins that were loaded during runtime to activate a invoke method.

In general, I'd recommend using a interface to interact with your command classes. In this way, all commands created by you, and other people will be easier to understand.

Comment: *"You cannot add a type to a list, since it is a type. You have to define an object to add it to the list.*" You can add a `Type` to a list, you just have to use the right generic parameters.

Comment: You can add an instance of the `Type` class, which is an object that contains metadata for a type. A list can be associated with a type, e.g. `List<string>` is associated with strings. But you cannot put types themselves in a list.